# How to check if IMAP Webklex is connected or not connected

Tags: laravel, email, imap

I'm having problems catching the error for the email webklex imap. i want to check if connected or not connected. credentials are correct, i only need to catch if the credentials are wrong or not connected.

Thanks.

```
$oClient = new Client([
    'host'          => 'imap.gmail.com',
    'port'          => $account_type['port'],
    'encryption'    => 'ssl',
    'validate_cert' => true,
    'username'      => $username,
    'password'      => $password,
    'protocol'      => 'imap'
]);
$oClient->connect();
if(){
//check if connected or not
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$oClient->isConnected();` or `$oClient->checkConnection();`
It really depends on your requirement.

For more information follow the documentation: https://github.com/Webklex/laravel-imap#clientclass